# Firebase Cloud Function Send Notification Error

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, promise, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to send a notification using Firebase Cloud Functions to all users whenever data is added to a certain collection within Firestore.

Here is my cloud function code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config.firebase);

exports.makeUppercase = functions.firestore.document('messages/{messageId}')
.onCreate((snap, context) => {
    const value = snap.data().original;
    console.log('notifying ' + value);

    return Promise.all([value]).then(result => {
        const value = result[0].data().value;

        const payload = {
            notification: {
                title: "Added",
                body: "Data Added"
            }
        };

        admin.messaging().send(payload, false).then(result => {
            console.log("Notification sent!");
        });
    });
});
```

When I'm trying to create this function using `firebase deploy --only functions`, I'm getting an error in console.

```
/Users/rachitgoyal/functions/index.js
  35:40  error  Each then() should return a value or throw  promise/always-return

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! functions@ lint: `eslint .`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/rachitgoyal/.npm/_logs/2019-05-08T08_36_48_838Z-debug.log

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code1
```

Additional logs from debug.log for reference:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   '--prefix',
1 verbose cli   '/Users/rachitgoyal/functions',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'lint' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v10.15.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'prelint', 'lint', 'postlint' ]
5 info lifecycle functions@~prelint: functions@
6 info lifecycle functions@~lint: functions@
7 verbose lifecycle functions@~lint: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle functions@~lint: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/rachitgoyal/functions/node_modules/.bin:/Users/rachitgoyal/.npm-global/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
9 verbose lifecycle functions@~lint: CWD: /Users/rachitgoyal/functions
10 silly lifecycle functions@~lint: Args: [ '-c', 'eslint .' ]
11 silly lifecycle functions@~lint: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle functions@~lint: Failed to exec lint script
13 verbose stack Error: functions@ lint: `eslint .`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:189:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
14 verbose pkgid functions@
15 verbose cwd /Users/rachitgoyal
16 verbose Darwin 18.5.0
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "--prefix" "/Users/rachitgoyal/functions" "run" "lint"
18 verbose node v10.15.3
19 verbose npm  v6.4.1
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error functions@ lint: `eslint .`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the functions@ lint script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

The funny thing here is that if I comment the below code in my index.js, the deployment works fine.

```
const payload = {
    notification: {
        title: "Added",
        body: "Data Added"
    }
};

admin.messaging().send(payload, false).then(result => {
    console.log("Notification sent!");
});
```

So I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong with the initialization of the notification. Or I'm not returning the values to Promise properly. Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you do `Promise.all([value])`? What is in `value`?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec It's a value that I want to display in the notification. I'm getting it from Firestore whenever a new document is added within a collection. Value is the value of a field within that document.

Comment: But you don't use it in the notification payload.

Comment: In any case it is still not not clear why you do `Promise.all([value])`. If I understand you correctly you get the value you want to send with `snap.data().original`, so you don't need to do anything anymore with `value`. Also, I don't think `[value]` is an array of Promises (which is what you need to pass to `Promise.all()`).

Comment: Ok, got it. I changed that but still didn't fix the issue.

Comment: If you want us to help you, you need to update your question with the modifications.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Sorry. Will do.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec your answer below fixed it for me. Thanks a lot for that. I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Promise.all()` and [`admin.messaging().send()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging.Messaging?authuser=0#send) both return a Promise, therefore you need to chain those promises.

However it is not clear why you do

```
const value = snap.data().original;
        console.log('notifying ' + value);

        return Promise.all([value])
        .then(result => {
            const value = result[0].data().value;
            ...
```

If you just want to use the value of `value` in your notification, you don't need to use `Promise.all()` at all and you should do as follows:

```
exports.makeUppercase = functions.firestore.document('messages/{messageId}')
.onCreate((snap, context) => {
    const value = snap.data().original;
    console.log('notifying ' + value);

     const payload = {
         notification: {
            title: "Added",
            body: value + "Data Added"  //Here we use value
         }
     };

    return admin.messaging().send(payload, false)
    .then(result => {  //Note that if you don't need the console.log you can get rid of this then()
         console.log("Notification sent!");
         return null;
    });
});
```